# How to get GitHub desktop's "git" tool working globally in cmd, PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, github-for-windows

I already have GitHub Desktop, it works great, but it doesn't make available **git** command in Powershell and Command Promt. And I don't want to download and install entire git-scm just for this convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it somewhere in the path, where windows automatically searches for executables, or extend path.

http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41, it helped! I added `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d7effa1a4a322478cd29c826b52a0c118ad3db11\cmd\` to the PATH, and it works great even in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: glad it helped ;)